# Comparando Listas em java?

Tags: java

Como comparar duas Listas e adicionar o registro diferente em uma terceira lista??

Ex: Lista 1(1,2,3,4) Lista 2(1,2,3) Lista3.add(4);

Comment: Depende o resultado que você quer. Qual é?

Comment: Tem que ser lista ou pode ser conjunto (`Set`)? No conjunto os elementos não se repetem, na lista sim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Teste {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> lista1 = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4);
        List<Integer> lista2 = Arrays.asList(1,2,3);

        //clona lista 1
        List<Integer> lista3 = new ArrayList<Integer>(lista1);

        // remove todos os intems da lista 2
        lista3.removeAll(lista2);

        System.out.println(lista3);

    }
}
```

Comment: Vlw Pela ajuda Marciano.